# Type Covariance runtime errors

Tags: c#, covariance

> C# 6.0 in a Nutshell by Joseph Albahari and Ben Albahari (O’Reilly).
>
> Copyright 2016 Joseph Albahari and Ben Albahari, 978-1-491-92706-9.

states, at pages 123-124, with regards to type covariance:

> Arrays, for historical reasons, array types support covariance. This
>   means that B[] can be cast to A[] if B subclasses A (and both are
>   reference types).
>
> For example:

```
Bear[] bears = new Bear[3]; 
Animal[] animals = bears; // OK
```

> The downside of this reusability is that element assignments can fail
>   at runtime:

```
animals[0] = new Camel(); // Runtime error
```

What is the reason behind such error ?
If you assign an instance of Bear to an instance of Animal, a runtime error will be thrown ? I do not see why it should (by allowing such an assignment, the compiler needs to take responsibility in stating "all right, I will let you do with this object everything that an animal can do." Since Bear is an animal, this incurs no problems whatsoever.

I created my own scenario to test the above:

```
public class X
{
    public int Num { get; set; }

    public void Method_1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("X");
    }

    public virtual void Method_2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Num);
    }
}

public class Y : X
{
    public Y()
    {
        Num = 1000;
    }
}

X[] arrayX = new X[] { new X { Num = 1000 }, new X { Num = 999 }, new X { Num = 51762 } };
Y[] arrayY = new Y[] { new Y { Num = 5 }, new Y { Num = 6 }, new Y { Num = 7 } };

X x = new X { Num = 1000 };
Y y = new Y { Num = 50 };

x = y;

arrayX = arrayY;

arrayX[2] = new Y { Num = 1 };

// will print 5,6,1 - no runtime errors faced
foreach (var e in arrayX)
    Console.WriteLine(e.Num);
```

I believe the snippet above mimics the book's example - but with my snippet, there are no runtime errors.

What am I missing ? How is `animals[0] = new Camel();` supposed to thrown a runtime error, as the book states ?

Comment: While the `animals` array looks like an array of animals it's actually an array of bears.  You cannot add a camel to an array of bears (clearly the bears would eat the camel).  Your example has animal (X) and bear (Y), but is missing a second child class like camel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the reason behind such error?

Because it is trying to store a `Camel` into an array with a runtime type of `Bear[]`. An array of type `Bear[]` can *only* store references to instances of `Bear` or subclasses. The compile-time type of `Animal[]` only says that it *might* be able to store a `Camel` reference, and that any reference you get *out* of the array will definitely be an `Animal` instance or subclass.

Your example is different. When we strip out all the properties etc (which are irrelevant) you've got:

```
X[] arrayX = new Y[3];
arrayX[2] = new Y();
```

That's fine - that's storing a reference to a `Y` object in an array with an execution-time type of `Y[]`. No problem.

To demonstrate the same problem as the book, you'd need a third class:

```
class Z : X {}

X[] arrayX = new Z[3];
arrayX[2] = new Y(); // Bang - can't store a Y reference in a Z[]
```

Comment: @Veverke: I'm not sure what you mean - but I'm now looking at your more involved example.

Comment: Hi Jon, my question is about the book's statement `animals[0] = new Camel(); // Runtime error`.

Comment: @Veverke That's what Jon answered.

Comment: That's right, I had in mind that the example dealed with one deriving class of animals only. But it deals with 2, and the fact that at runtime the array type will be closed on Bear starts to clarify things.

Answer (score 1):

Your example with X and Y is quite different than the one from book.
If you would like to mimic the one from book, create abstract base class X and then make Y and Z derive from it. Then, play around with it.
The one from book implies that:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bear[] bears = new Bear[3];
        Animal[] animals = bears;
        animals[0] = new Camel(); //will throw on runtime
    }
}

public abstract class Animal { }

public class Camel : Animal { }

public class Bear : Animal { }
```

As Jon already stated, runtime type of `animals` will be `Bear[]` which simply cannot store an instance of `Camel`.
Also please notice, that's a possible error for covariant array conversion, but not gonna happen for other collections like `List`:

```
        List<Bear> bearsList = new List<Bear>();
        List<Animal> animalsList = bearsList; //won't compile because of this error
        animalsList[0] = new Camel();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the following line:

```
Animal[] animals = bears;
```

You are just *hiding* your `Bear[]` into an `Animal[]`.

Note that I say *hiding*, because you are not actually creating a new array.

Both `bears` and `animals` point to the same `Bear[]`, the only difference is that `animals` is hiding that reference as `Animal[]`.

---

The compiler does not know this.

For the compiler, if you want to store a `Dolphin`, or a `Lion` on `animals`, it will let you do so, since all those elements are of type `Animal`.

---

The runtime however would complain.

Since `animals` hides a `Bear[]`, adding a `Camel` to it will not be allowed.

Although `Bear` and `Camel` both inherit from `Animal`, they are two different types.

Answer (score 0):

For this code:

```
Animal[] bears = new Bear[3];
```

If you installed Resharper in your VS, it gives the same warning of:

> Co-variant array conversion from Bear[] to Animal[] can cause run-time
>   exception on write operation.

If you use Generic such as IList:

```
IList<Animal> bears = new List<Bear>();
bears.Add(new Camel());
```

the first line won't let you compile, which is safer, prevents it from possible run-time exception.